How do add attachments (pdf) to points in a shapefile using the "Enable Attachments" tool?
I have a shapefile consisting of several hundred thousand addresses. I need to link related pdf files to each point in the shapefile based off a designated variable. In the shapefile I have a column labeled "UNITID" and in my folder containing the PDFs, all the files are labeled by the UNITID. Is there a way to link the PDFs to the points?

There's probably several ways, but most of them will involve creating a table containing the ID values and file path, then joining to it. Please make an attempt to solve the task and  [Edit] the Question to specify what you have tried.

Are you using ArcGIS Pro to do this or something else?

If all the PDFs are in the same folder you could add a new text field and calculate field as follows (Arcade example) using absolute or relative paths:
'C:\\folder\\subfolder\\' + $feature.UNITIDfieldname + '.pdf'
To open the file, Ctrl + click the link in the attribute table.
